# when I use android 4.1 default icon, it prompts "Error: No resource found ", why it is like this?

Tags: android, icons, default

**I want to use the android default preference icon**

```
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**and it prompts this error...**

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_preferences
```

how could I use the default icon??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android default preference icon use

```
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

instead of

```
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: thanks! how about refresh? android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh" this doesnt work